Notes not showing up on Main View (Flutter App)
Ive been following freecodecamp 37 hour flutter course by Vandad.
The course was running smoothly without any problem until 21:50:42, when he teaches how to show all notes in main ui. Ive wrote the similar code, but unable to show all my notes in main ui.
Im also sharing my related code files below.
The only difference i have is in my new note view file where is write _note = snapshot.data; rather than _note = snapshot.data as DatabaseNote as done in the course because i was facing a null error(click here to see detail - type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'DatabaseNotes' in type cast) when i did the latter .
Notes View
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:developer' as devtools show log;
import 'package:mynotes/constants/routes.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/enums/menu_action.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/crud/notes_service.dart';
// import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class NotesView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotesView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotesView> createState() => _NotesViewState();
}

class _NotesViewState extends State<NotesView> {
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  String get userEmail => AuthService.firebase().currentUser!.email;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('MAIN UI'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(newNoteRoute);
              },
              icon: const Icon(Icons.add)),
          PopupMenuButton<MenuAction>(
            onSelected: (value) async {
              switch (value) {
                case MenuAction.logout:
                  final shouldLogout = await showLogoutDialog(context);
                  devtools.log(shouldLogout.toString());
                  if (shouldLogout) {
                    await AuthService.firebase().logOut();
                    // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                      loginRoute,
                      (_) => false,
                    );
                  }
                // break;
              }
            },
            itemBuilder: (context) {
              return const [
                PopupMenuItem<MenuAction>(
                  value: MenuAction.logout,
                  child: Text('Logout'),
                )
              ];
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: _notesService.getOrCreateUser(email: userEmail),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              return StreamBuilder(
                stream: _notesService.allNote,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    case ConnectionState.active:
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        final allNotes = snapshot.data as List<DatabaseNotes>;
                        return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: allNotes.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            final note = allNotes[index];
                            return ListTile(
                              title: Text(
                                note.text,
                                maxLines: 1,
                                softWrap: true,
                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        );
                      } else {
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    default:
                      return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
                },
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future<bool> showLogoutDialog(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog<bool>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: const Text('Sign out'),
        content: const Text('Are you sure you want to sign out.'),
        actions: [
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
            },
            child: const Text('Cancel'),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            },
            child: const Text('Logout'),
          ),
        ],
      );
    },
  ).then((value) => value ?? false);
}


New Note View
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/auth/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/crud/notes_service.dart';

class NewNoteView extends StatefulWidget {
  const NewNoteView({super.key});

  @override
  State<NewNoteView> createState() => _NewNoteViewState();
}

class _NewNoteViewState extends State<NewNoteView> {
  DatabaseNotes? _note;
  late final NotesService _notesService;
  late final TextEditingController _textController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _notesService = NotesService();
    _textController = TextEditingController();
    super.initState();
  }

  void _textControllerListener() async {
    final note = _note;
    if (note == null) {
      return;
    }

    final text = _textController.text;
    await _notesService.updateNote(
      note: note,
      text: text,
    );
  }

  void _setupTextControllerListener() {
    _textController.removeListener(_textControllerListener);
    _textController.addListener(_textControllerListener);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> createNewNote() async {
    final existingNote = _note;

    if (existingNote != null) {
      return existingNote;
    }

    final currentUser = AuthService.firebase().currentUser!;
    final email = currentUser.email;
    final owner = await _notesService.getUser(email: email);
    return await _notesService.createNote(owner: owner);
  }

  void _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty() {
    final note = _note;

    if (_textController.text.isEmpty && note != null) {
      _notesService.deleteNote(id: note.id);
    }
  }

  void _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty() async {
    final note = _note;
    final text = _textController.text;

    if (note != null && text.isNotEmpty) {
      await _notesService.updateNote(
        note: note,
        text: text,
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _deleteNoteIfTextIsEmpty();
    _saveNoteIfTextNotEmpty();
    _textController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('New Note'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: createNewNote(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.done:
              _note = snapshot.data;
              _setupTextControllerListener();
              return TextField(
                controller: _textController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Enter your note',
                ),
              );
            default:
              return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


Notes Service
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mynotes/services/crud/crud_exceptions.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' show join;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
// import 'package:sqflite/sqlite_api.dart';

class NotesService {
  Database? _db;

  List<DatabaseNotes> _notes = [];

  // singleton
  static final NotesService _shared = NotesService._sharedInstance();
  NotesService._sharedInstance() {
    _notesStreamController = StreamController<List<DatabaseNotes>>.broadcast(
      onListen: () {
        _notesStreamController.sink.add(_notes);
      },
    );
  }
  factory NotesService() => _shared;

  late final StreamController<List<DatabaseNotes>> _notesStreamController;

  Stream<List<DatabaseNotes>> get allNote => _notesStreamController.stream;

  Future<DatabaseUser> getOrCreateUser({required String email}) async {
    try {
      final user = await getUser(email: email);
      return user;
    } on CouldNotFindUser {
      final createdUser = createUser(email: email);
      return createdUser;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _cacheNotes() async {
    final allNotes = await getAllNotes();
    _notes = allNotes.toList();
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> updateNote({
    required DatabaseNotes note,
    required String text,
  }) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    // make sure note exists
    await getNote(id: note.id);

    // update db
    final updateCount = await db.update(noteTable, {
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 0,
    });

    if (updateCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNoteUpdateNote();
    } else {
      final updatedNote = await getNote(id: note.id);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == updatedNote.id);
      _notes.add(updatedNote);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return updatedNote;
    }
  }

  Future<Iterable<DatabaseNotes>> getAllNotes() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final notes = await db.query(noteTable);

    return notes.map((noteRow) => DatabaseNotes.fromRow(noteRow));
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> getNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final notes = await db.query(
      noteTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (notes.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindNotes();
    } else {
      final note = DatabaseNotes.fromRow(notes.first);
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notes.add(note);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
      return note;
    }
  }

  Future<int> deleteAllNote() async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final numberOfDeletions = await db.delete(noteTable);

    _notes = [];
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return numberOfDeletions;
  }

  Future<void> deleteNote({required int id}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      noteTable,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: [id],
    );

    if (deletedCount == 0) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteNote();
    } else {
      _notes.removeWhere((note) => note.id == id);
      _notesStreamController.add(_notes);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseNotes> createNote({required DatabaseUser owner}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    // make sure the owner exists in the database with correct id.
    final dbUser = await getUser(email: owner.email);
    if (dbUser != owner) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    }

    const text = '';

    // create note
    final noteId = await db.insert(noteTable, {
      userIdColumn: owner.id,
      textColumn: text,
      isSyncedWithCloudColumn: 1,
    });

    final note = DatabaseNotes(
      id: noteId,
      userId: owner.id,
      text: text,
      isSyncedWithCloud: true,
    );

    _notes.add(note);
    _notesStreamController.add(_notes);

    return note;
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> getUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final result = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (result.isEmpty) {
      throw CouldNotFindUser();
    } else {
      return DatabaseUser.fromRow(result.first);
    }
  }

  Future<DatabaseUser> createUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();

    final result = await db.query(
      userTable,
      limit: 1,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (result.isNotEmpty) {
      throw UserAlreadyExists();
    }

    final userId = await db.insert(userTable, {
      emailColumn: [email.toLowerCase()]
    });

    return DatabaseUser(
      id: userId,
      email: email,
    );
  }

  Future<void> deleteUser({required String email}) async {
    await _ensureDbIsOpen();
    final db = _getDatabaseOrThrow();
    final deletedCount = await db.delete(
      userTable,
      where: 'email = ?',
      whereArgs: [email.toLowerCase()],
    );

    if (deletedCount != 1) {
      throw CouldNotDeleteUser();
    }
  }

  Database _getDatabaseOrThrow() {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      return db;
    }
  }

  Future<void> open() async {
    if (_db != null) {
      throw DatabaseAlreadyOpenException();
    }

    try {
      final docsPath = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final dbPath = join(docsPath.path, dbName);
      final db = await openDatabase(dbPath);
      _db = db;

      // create user table
      await db.execute(createUserTable);
      // create note table
      await db.execute(createNoteTable);
      await _cacheNotes();
    } on MissingPlatformDirectoryException {
      throw UnableToGetDocumentsDirectory();
    }
  }

  Future<void> close() async {
    final db = _db;
    if (db == null) {
      throw DatabaseIsNotOpen();
    } else {
      await db.close();
      _db = null;
    }
  }

  Future<void> _ensureDbIsOpen() async {
    try {
      await open();
    } on DatabaseAlreadyOpenException {
      // empty
    }
  }
}

@immutable
class DatabaseUser {
  final int id;
  final String email;

  // what is required???
  const DatabaseUser({
    required this.id,
    required this.email,
  });

  DatabaseUser.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColum] as int,
        email = map[emailColumn] as String;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Person, ID = $id, email = $email';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseUser other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

class DatabaseNotes {
  final int id;
  final int userId;
  final String text;
  final bool isSyncedWithCloud;

  DatabaseNotes({
    required this.id,
    required this.userId,
    required this.text,
    required this.isSyncedWithCloud,
  });

  DatabaseNotes.fromRow(Map<String, Object?> map)
      : id = map[idColum] as int,
        userId = map[emailColumn] as int,
        text = map[textColumn] as String,
        isSyncedWithCloud =
            (map[isSyncedWithCloudColumn] as int) == 1 ? true : false;

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'Note, id = $id, user_id = $userId, is_synced_with_cloud = $isSyncedWithCloud, text = $text';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant DatabaseNotes other) => id == other.id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}

const dbName = 'notes.db';
const noteTable = 'note';
const userTable = 'user';
const idColum = 'id';
const emailColumn = 'email';
const userIdColumn = 'user_id';
const textColumn = 'text';
const isSyncedWithCloudColumn = 'is_synced_with_cloud';
const createNoteTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "note" (
                                "id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                "user_id"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                "text"  TEXT,
                                "id_synced_with_cloud"  INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                                PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT),
                                FOREIGN KEY("user_id") REFERENCES "user"("id")
                              );''';
const createUserTable = '''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "user" (
                                  "id"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
                                  "email"   TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                  PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
                                );''';


I tried the following things to fix.
~ Try running my app on android emulator(android studio) instead of ios simulator(xcode).
~ Tried to look for any difference in my code and the code written in course when i couldn't find any difference i went to the course git and literally copied the code from then and adjusted the spelling slightly to run (didn't help).

avoid using
late final NotesService _notesService;
late final TextEditingController _textController;
instead, use
NotesService? _notesService;
TextEditingController? _textController; all the places replace with like above and then try again

this wont work as NotesService and TextEditingController functions will give an compile time error as to use the functions its compulsory that they are not nullable.
